# How to print messages in console in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm using below code to test login to a website.The code opens a webpage and wait for an element to load and then logs in using the provided credentials. I have put some messages in the code for me to identify whether the code is running. However, it is not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()

options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

s = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
url = "https://atf.domain.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)

try:
# wait 10 seconds before looking for element
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
    print("Page loaded!")
)
except TimeoutException:
print("Page not loaded!")


driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("email@gmail.com")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "signinButton").click()

try:
# wait 10 seconds before looking for element
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "compose-delivery-link"))
    print("Compose delivery page loaded!")
)
except TimeoutException:
print("Compose delivery page not loaded!")

driver.find_element(By.ID, "compose-delivery-link").click()


driver.close()
```

I'm getting below error,

```
File "sft_login_test.py", line 24
print('Page loaded!')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no tried idea how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
)
print("Page loaded!")
```

I guess the `print` call should be outside the `.until` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally wrote a call to `print()` inside the parentheses of `.until()`
Both at **line 23**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
    print("Page loaded!")
)
```

and at **line 37**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "compose-delivery-link"))
    print("Compose delivery page loaded!")
)
```

Additionally, you're gonna want to import the `TimeoutException` from `selenium.common.exceptions`, because that's likely the next error you will encounter.

And to give some side Information, `WebDriverWait` doesn't actually wait 10 seconds before looking for the element. It rather checks for the condition *(here the presence of an element with ID "name" or "password" respectively)* in a set interval until it either finds the element, in which case the element is returned, or the time limit *(here 10 seconds)* is reached, in which case it throws a `TimeoutException`.